# Retrieving data from a ViewModel in POST method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a View model that looks like this

```
 public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemComponentViewModel> Components{ get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentPartViewModel> ComponentParts { get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentSubCompViewModel> ComponentSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompPartViewModel> SubCompParts { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompSubCompViewModel> SubCompSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompSubCompPartViewModel> SubCompSubCompParts { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see the Viewmodel also has corresponding view models that look like this

```
public class ItemPartViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PartID { get; set; }
        public HtmlString PartLink { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public float QtyInItem { get; set; }
        public float OnHand { get; set; }
        public float OnWorkOrder { get; set; }
        public float Committed { get; set; }
        public float FSTK { get; set; }

        // This is the additional property to contain what user picks
        public PartActionType SelectedActionType { get; set; }
    }
```

The ItemViewModel is populated through my OrderSelection GET method that looks like this

```
 public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(id);
            if (jobOrder == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
            ItemInstance ii = db.ItemInstances.Where(x => x.serialNumber == jobOrder.serialNumber).FirstOrDefault();
            Item item = db.Items.Find(ii.ItemID);

            var vm = new ItemViewModel
            {
                Id = item.ID,
                ItemId = item.ItemID,
                ItemName = item.Name,
                Parts = new List<ItemPartViewModel>(),
                Components = new List<ItemComponentViewModel>(),
                ComponentParts = new List<ComponentPartViewModel>(),
                ComponentSubComps = new List<ComponentSubCompViewModel>(),
                SubCompParts = new List<SubCompPartViewModel>(),
                SubCompSubComps = new List<SubCompSubCompViewModel>(),
                SubCompSubCompParts = new List<SubCompSubCompPartViewModel>()
            };

            foreach (ItemHasParts ihp in item.IHP)
            {
                Part part = db.Parts.Find(ihp.PartID);
               

                vm.Parts.Add(new ItemPartViewModel
                {
                    ID = part.ID,
                    PartID = part.PartID,
                    PartLink = part.PartIDLink,
                    MFGNumber = part.MFG_number,
                    QtyInItem = ihp.qty,
                    OnHand = part.On_Hand,
                    OnWorkOrder = part.On_Order_Count(true, true),
                    Committed = part.CommittedCount(true, true),
                    FSTK = part.FSTK,
                    PartName = part.Name,
                    SelectedActionType = PartActionType.Transfer
                });
            }

    return View(vm);
}
```

The data then is correctly shown on the selection page. But on this page users must select whether they want to harvest/transfer/or dispose of a part. So once the user has finished selecting their options they hit a 'submit' button. This then POSTS to this method

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(ItemViewModel model)
        {
            //list of transfers
            //list of harvests
            //list of disposals      
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.Id);
                if (jobOrder == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
                // do whatever with 'model' and return or redirect to a View
            }

            //ViewBag.submitted = true;
            return RedirectToAction("SpecialOrderSummary", new { ID = jobOrder.ID });   

        }
```

The problem here is that for each list, (Parts/Components/ComponentParts/etc.) The ID is null. Why is it null on the POST but not the GET? And how can I fix this so it is not null

Here is the beginning of my View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <h2 class="noprint">Special Order Selection</h2>
            <p style="color:red" class="noprint">Please select what is to be done with each component/part</p>

            <td align="left">


                <hr class="noprint" />
                <h4 class="noprint"><b>Work Order ID:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(model => j.ID)</h4>
                <br class="noprint" />
```

And here is the payload of it

```
<form action="/JODetails/SpecialOrderSelection/3092" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="LETTERSANDNUMBERS" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="3092" />        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <h2 class="noprint">Special Order Selection</h2>
            <p style="color:red" class="noprint">Please select what is to be done with each component/part</p>
```

Here is an example of what a 'Part' in my 'parts' list is returning

[image: Part]

Comment: could you please add the post request body that causes the error?

Comment: Do you have the id in a hidden field on your view?  If not, that's a problem.

Comment: @ddfra There really isn't an 'error' but I added into my question an example of what the Model is returning

Comment: @devlincarnate Yes I do

Comment: It would be better if you past what chrome (or another browser) shows in the network tab of the developer tools for your post request. I'm interested in the request payload

Comment: Can you update your question and show us the Id in the view.  Most helpful would be to see the F12  Elements view, where we can see the hidden input as well as the value of the Id.

Comment: insure you have the id in hidden field inside the form

Comment: @ddfra Okay I added it in

Comment: @devlincarnate Okay I added it in

Comment: @khaledsaleh I had it, but I added it in to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hidden field in the form is `Id`, which is the Model.Id (ItemViewModel) and not the part! and yet the property you're inspecting on POST is `ID` (which is the Part ID).  You're looking for the item part ID, but you only have the ItemViewModel Id in the form.  Since you have other values for item part properties, you must be iterating over that list of parts somewhere in your form.  Add a hidden input for the part ID there.

```
@{
  foreach(var part in Model.Parts) {
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => part.ID)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem